# Implementing Interface OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, xml, onclick, onclicklistener

**Edit: **

The main reason I'm asking this is the code below, *it implements the OnClickListener* but didn't set **new OnClickListener** instead only passed the context as parameter to OnClickListener.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener { 
  ImageSwitcher imageSwitcher; 
        Button btnPrevios, btnNext; 
        int[] LOGO = {  R.drawable.barca,     R.drawable.psg,  }; 
        int currentIndex = -1; 
     @Override 
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
       btnPrevios = //.......;  btnNext = //.....;
            btnPrevios.setOnClickListener(this); 
            btnPrevios.setOnClickListener(this); 
        imageSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.imageSwitcher); 
         imageSwitcher.setFactory(new ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory() { 
                @Override 
           //.......
            }); 
        } 
     
        public void onClick(View view) { 
            switch (view.getId()){ 
                case R.id.btnNext: 
                    if(currentIndex<LOGO.length-1){ 
                        currentIndex = currentIndex+1; 
                        imageSwitcher.setBackgroundResource(LOGO[currentIndex]); 
                    } 
                    break; 
        } 
    }
```

**But the Xml still needs the onClick as shown below**

```
      <Button 
                android:id="@+id/btnPrevious" 
                android:onClick="onClick"  />  
                <Button 
                 android:id="@+id/btnNext" 
                  android:onClick="onClick" 
                        />
```

** Please what's the purpose of Implementing OnClickListener in the case above**

**Edit :** From the comments i realized probably y'all don't understand my question.

*according to Mark*

`If you've implemented and set the OnClickListener in code, you do not need the android:onClick attribute in the layout XML`

But the codes I've seen so far implements the
Interface OnClickListener and did

```
button.setOnClickListener(this);
```

But none of them did use

```
setOnClickListener(new onClickListener);
```

as *Pirho* stated.

They did

```
Public void onClick(View v){
//sth
}
```

**which is either confusing or more of a tautology as compared to my Method.

It seems I'm missing something**

How does the Xml onClick work in code or am I missing something. I do write my onClick methods like this

```
Public void onClick(View v){
//sth
}
```

Without implementing the Interface View.OnClickListener after extending the  Activity class and it does work well.

But recently I saw something like this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
//.......

button.setOnClickListener(this);

}

Public void onClick(View v){
//sth
}
```

**Please What's is the purpose of implementing the interface View.OnClickListener** since i still have to state **onClick="onClick"** like i always do in my xml.

Comment: If you've implemented and set the `OnClickListener` in code, you do not need the `android:onClick` attribute in the layout XML.

Comment: And just by putting android:onClick="onClick" the activity will not be implementing the View.OnClickListner instead it will be just pointing towards a method to execute it can be anything not onClick only

Comment: Just adding to comment from Mike M that yout need also to do `setOnClickListener(onClickListener);` where ever it is used and to comment from AgentP that the method registered in XML just must have param `View v`.

Comment: It's even less clear what you're asking now. Are you wondering why you don't have to implement `OnClickListener` when you use the `android:onClick` attribute?

Comment: Unfortunately none of this answers my question, I' ve updated my question so if you can kindly be of help

Comment: Yes Mike, The Reason why i don't have to implement OnClickListener when I use the android:onClick attribute *and* why the guy who wrote the code in my new edit have to implement OnClickListener since he is also using android:onClick

Comment: Ah, OK. When you use the `android:onClick` attribute, the `LayoutInflater` uses reflection to access the specified method in the `Activity`, and then sets a generic `OnClickListener` on the `Button` that just invokes that method through reflection. The `Activity` doesn't need to implement the interface for that. It's that internal `LayoutInflater` object that's the `OnClickListener`. As for that code using both, it's redundant, and possibly they just forgot about the XML attributes. The ones set in code override the ones from the layout, though, even though they both use the same method here.

Comment: wow,nice to know that. Great.....              
    Would love to mark this as the correct answer for future viewers to see and also learn from it....

Comment: Actually, in a regular `Activity`, the `android:onClick` attribute is handled in the `View` class. In support/androidx classes – e.g., `AppCompatActivity` – it's handled in the `LayoutInflater`. They both do the same thing, basically, but I should state that correctly. I'll try to see about a proper answer later on, when I get some time. Hope everything's clear now. Cheers!

Comment: Oh ok thanks, i would really like to ask a question the androidx you mentioned. This is 2020, should i still use AppCompatActivity(is it still supported)  or switch to androidX. Although i still extending Normal Activity atm

Comment: Current recommendations are to use androidx, unless you have some really basic app that can use only non-deprecated platform classes. `AppCompatActivity` is still in androidx, and it's perfectly fine to use. When they migrated, they kept the same basic names for pretty much everything; it's all just in androidx now. If you create a new project in recent Android Studio versions, it'll be using androidx by default.